# How to add a cutscene in UPBGE 3.0?

Tags: node-editor, game-engine, video

How to add a cutscene in UPBGE 3.0?
All the tutorials on YouTube are outdated and don't seem to work on the newer versions of UPBGE.

I tried the method on GitHub (https://github.com/UPBGE/upbge/issues/1073#issuecomment-551172122) but it did not work for me, so I tried using the video as an image texture but it only plays in the viewport (still image when I press  <kbd>P</kbd>). Could anyone suggest a solution?

I would like to be able to see the cutscene when I press play, then I can add delay and change scene nodes to switch to the gameplay.

[image]

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/UPBGE/upbge/issues/1073#issuecomment-551172122) might explain the solution you need.

Comment: if Martys comment doesn't help, maybe you should describe a bit more what you want to achieve...

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please write all the content of your question in the body of the post. Also state what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Turns out animating it was the answer. Thanks for the comments before. https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-add-a-cutscene-in-upbge-3-0/1356564/3